# Неправильная отработка метода по обновлению информации

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, hibernate

Метод в DAO отвечающий за обновление(проверено, работает верно).

```
  public boolean update(EmployeeEntity employeeEntityUpdate) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    try {
        session.beginTransaction();
        Query query = session.createQuery("update EmployeeEntity set id =:id, name =:name, surname =:surname, age = :age, employedDate =:employedDate, login =:login, password = :password, role= :role");
        query.setParameter("name", employeeEntityUpdate.getName());
        query.setParameter("surname", employeeEntityUpdate.getSurname());
        query.setParameter("age", employeeEntityUpdate.getAge());
        query.setParameter("employedDate", employeeEntityUpdate.getEmployedDate());
        query.setParameter("login", employeeEntityUpdate.getLogin());
        query.setParameter("password", employeeEntityUpdate.getPassword());
        query.setParameter("role", employeeEntityUpdate.getRole());
        query.setParameter("id", employeeEntityUpdate.getId());

        query.executeUpdate();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        return true;
    }
    catch (HibernateException exc) {
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Скриншот окна, где выбирается один из пользователей со списка(всегда при выборе только самого верхнего система будет его обновлять и вносить соответствующую информацию в базу данных

[image: )]

*Здесь employeeEntity - объявлена статической и именно это поле передается в метод onActionUpdate, то есть при нажатии клавиши Update далее.*

Метод при нажатии кнопки "Edit"

```
 @FXML
void onActionEdit(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    mainController = new MainController();
    employeeEntity = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    if (employeeEntity == null) {
        mainController.newScene("/javafx/employeeNotChosenError.fxml");
    }
    else {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/javafx/windowEdit.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        Controller4 controller4 = loader.getController();
        controller4.setNameEdit(employeeEntity.getName());
        controller4.setSurnameEdit(employeeEntity.getSurname());
        controller4.setAgeEdit(employeeEntity.getAge());
        controller4.setDatePicker(employeeEntity.getEmployedDate());
        controller4.setRole(employeeEntity.getRole().toString());
        btnEdit.getScene().setRoot(root);
    }
}
```

После выбора пользователя и нажатия "Edit":
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Описание самого метода Update:

```
 @FXML
void onActionUpdate(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    EmployeeService servicex = new EmployeeServiceImpl();
    EmployeeEntity employeeEntity = Controller2.employeeEntity;
    System.out.println(employeeEntity.toString());
    employeeEntity.setName(txtFieldName.getText());
    employeeEntity.setSurname(txtFieldSurname.getText());
    employeeEntity.setAge(Integer.parseInt(txtFieldAge.getText()));
    Date date = Date.from(datePicker.getValue().atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
    employeeEntity.setEmployedDate(date);
    employeeEntity.setRole(Role.valueOf(roleSt.getValue().toString()));
    servicex.update(Controller2.employeeEntity);
    Stage stage = (Stage) btnUpdate.getScene().getWindow();
    stage.close();
    MainController.mainController.changeScene("/javafx/window2.fxml");
}
```

Ошибка после отработки кода:
**2017 12:50:34 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Duplicate entry '41' for key 'PRIMARY'** 
Данная ошибка вылетает при отработке всегда, любого объекта(включая первый из списка), однако значение первого изменяется в БД и в таблице, других - нет.

Comment: у вас еще и архитектура не правильная. прочитайте про паттерн MVC и  реализуйте его.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот этот код

```
Query query = session.createQuery("update EmployeeEntity set id =:id, name =:name, surname =:surname, age = :age, employedDate =:employedDate, login =:login, password = :password, role= :role");
query.setParameter("name", employeeEntityUpdate.getName());
query.setParameter("surname", employeeEntityUpdate.getSurname());
query.setParameter("age", employeeEntityUpdate.getAge());
query.setParameter("employedDate", employeeEntityUpdate.getEmployedDate());
query.setParameter("login", employeeEntityUpdate.getLogin());
query.setParameter("password", employeeEntityUpdate.getPassword());
query.setParameter("role", employeeEntityUpdate.getRole());
query.setParameter("id", employeeEntityUpdate.getId());
```

Замените на

```
Query query = session.createQuery("update EmployeeEntity set name =:name, surname =:surname, age = :age, employedDate =:employedDate, login =:login, password = :password, role= :role where id = :id");
query.setParameter("name", employeeEntityUpdate.getName());
query.setParameter("surname", employeeEntityUpdate.getSurname());
query.setParameter("age", employeeEntityUpdate.getAge());
query.setParameter("employedDate", employeeEntityUpdate.getEmployedDate());
query.setParameter("login", employeeEntityUpdate.getLogin());
query.setParameter("password", employeeEntityUpdate.getPassword());
query.setParameter("role", employeeEntityUpdate.getRole());
query.setParameter("id", employeeEntityUpdate.getId());
```

Вы не должны обновлять поле ключа - вы должны выбрать запись по нему. А то ваш код пытается обновить все записи в базе, а не только нужную вам.